# Armadillo function normalise() - getting warnings

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

I wrote that code and when I compile it I get so many warning:

CHECK HERE

[image]

```
arma::vec vv0={xx[0], yy[0], zz[0]};
arma::vec vv1={xx[1], yy[1], zz[1]};
arma::vec vv4={xx[4], yy[4], zz[4]};

arma::vec normal1 = normalise(cross(vv1-vv4, vv0-vv4));
```

Comment: It seems you're adding Armadillo as a header with source code and not as a precompiled source. Compile Armadillo THEN use it. There's no way to get rid of these warnings assuming you don't want to modify Armadillo. Btw, next time copy the error messages here and don't take a screenshot. You're using Qt Creator apparently, so find these warnings in the "Compiler Output" tab at the bottom.

Comment: What I should change to eliminate that errors?

Comment: Compile armadillo, then use it. That's my only guess from the limited information I have from your question.

Comment: How can I compile armadillo? :D I don't get any warnings without using normalise() function.

Comment: Needs some work. See [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) first, then google it.

Comment: Ok thanks, it is working :)

Comment: @lereviroda : Please [edit] those error messages directly into your question.  Questions should be standalone, not require external websites like pastebin.

Comment: @lereviroda : If you have got it working, please add an answer here so that future visitors can find it.